# Serve assets of multiple Angular apps from the same server with Nginx

Tags: angular, nginx

I'm serving multiple angular apps from the same server block in Nginx. I'm forwarding these routes from nginx to each angular app's index.html, I've added a try_files to each location:

```
    listen 80;
    server_name website.com;

    # project1
    location / {
        root /home/www/html/project1/dist/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    # project2
    location /project2/ {
        root /home/www/html/project2/dist/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

This solution avoids the 404 error when going to an Angular route, but the problem is that how could I route to assetes of each project

```
location /assets{
      ??
    }
```

Is there any config in nginx so without making changes in angular code , or change places of each project assets ?